# Why can't I link to boost's thread libraries?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, cmake

I am using Mac OS 10.11, and clang as my C/C++ compiler.
I installed boost with the easiest way `brew install boost`

First I tried these code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::array<int, 4> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::cout << arr[3];
    return 0;
}
```

It could work fine. So it seems that boost is set up correctly.

But when to try to use `#include<boost/thread.hpp>` and the example code as shown below:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void wait(int seconds)
{
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds{seconds});
}

void thread()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        wait(1);
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread t{thread};
    t.join();
}
```

Then I got these

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /Users/vita-nove/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug --target untitled -- -j 4
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable untitled
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::this_thread::hidden::sleep_for(timespec const&)", referenced from:
  boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::duration<long long,    boost::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > const&) in main.cpp.o
  "boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()", referenced from:
  boost::detail::thread_data<void (*)()>::~thread_data() in main.cpp.o
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
  boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int, char const*) in main.cpp.o
  ___cxx_global_var_init.2 in main.cpp.o
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
  ___cxx_global_var_init in main.cpp.o
  ___cxx_global_var_init.1 in main.cpp.o
  "boost::thread::join_noexcept()", referenced from:
  boost::thread::join() in main.cpp.o
  "boost::thread::native_handle()", referenced from:
  boost::thread::get_id() const in main.cpp.o
  "boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()", referenced from:
  boost::thread::start_thread() in main.cpp.o
  "boost::thread::detach()", referenced from:
  boost::thread::~thread() in main.cpp.o
  "typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base", referenced from:
  typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data<void (*)()> in main.cpp.o
  "vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base", referenced from:
  boost::detail::thread_data_base::thread_data_base() in main.cpp.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [untitled] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [untitled] Error 2
```

I google this problem for a while. I tried to set library dir `set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS /usr/local/lib)
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})`.

My CMakeLists.txt is here:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS /usr/local/lib)
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

I also tried `clang++ main.cpp -lboost_thread-mt`.
And then got these:

```
vita-nove@MacBook-Pro:~/CLionProjects/untitled$ clang++ main.cpp -lboost_thread-mt
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
  boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int, char const*) in main-964777.o
  ___cxx_global_var_init.2 in main-964777.o
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
  ___cxx_global_var_init in main-964777.o
  ___cxx_global_var_init.1 in main-964777.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone give me some help? Thank you very much!

---

UPDATE:
with the find_package command as @Angew said, I got some new error.

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /Users/vita-nove/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug --target untitled -- -j 4
CMake Warning at /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:744 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version 106300
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:848 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1435 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


-- Boost version: 1.63.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (add_executable):
  Target "untitled" links to target "Boost::thread" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/vita-nove/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

---

UPDATE

I tried some elder version of boost but sill the same. 
And if I use `target_include_directories(untitled PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})` and `target_link_libraries(untitled ${Boost_LIBRARIES})`

```
Scanning dependencies of target untitled
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable untitled
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
  boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int, char const*) in main.cpp.o
  ___cxx_global_var_init.2 in main.cpp.o
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
  ___cxx_global_var_init in main.cpp.o
  ___cxx_global_var_init.1 in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [untitled] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

UPDATE

@Angew found the true answer.

> I've updated the answer again. It seems Boost.Thread requires you to use Boost.System too. This would be handled by the imported targets, but since you can't use those, you apparently have to explicitly request it.

`find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread system)` makes it work fine.

Comment: It appears you're using CMake. Can you provide the relevant part of your `CMakeLists.txt`? (How you find Boost and how you set up your executable to use it).

Comment: @Angew Yes sure, updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct CMake way to interface with third-party packages is to use a [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) call, which will use either a find module (shipped with CMake), or a package config file (shipped by the third-party package), to locate the necessary libraries, directories etc.

In the case of Boost, there is a find module shipped with CMake itself. It offers a very tunable interface, you can read its [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) for details. However, here's the most basic way you could use it:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)
add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(untitled Boost::thread)
```

---

Based on this message you're receiving:

> Imported targets not available for Boost version 106300

it seems the imported-target approach cannot be used with your version of Boost. You will therefore have to fall back to variables provided by the find module:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread system)

add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
target_include_directories(untitled PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(untitled ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Thank you! I got error like `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (add_executable):
  Target "untitled" links to target "Boost::thread" but the target was not
  found.` Maybe I should tell CMake where boost is?

Comment: @AmorFati Do you actually have the appropriate version of Boost.Thread built? BTW, if it didn't fail with something like "Cannot find Boost" on the `find_package` line, then Boost was found successfully (notice the use of `REQUIRED`).

Comment: Thank you, this time is much further. btw, I have a question here. As you can see, `boost/array.hpp` can be included and linked successfully. So what's the differences between array.hpp and thread.hpp that make all these problem happen?

Comment: @AmorFati Most Boost libraries are header-only, which means they are not linked at all. That's also the case of Boost.Array. Just a few Boost libraries have compiled parts and thus need linking. Boost.Thread is one of them. Refer to [Boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries) for details.

Comment: @AmorFati I've updated the answer again. It seems Boost.Thread requires you to use Boost.System too. This would be handled by the imported targets, but since you can't use those, you apparently have to explicitly request it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Requesting system does help, now I can use boost::thread. The documents you refer also help me a lot.